# I'm trying to split this "for" loop to create 5 different DIV elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

thank you for passing by. I'm really a newbie and I'm trying to do (by taking some code, hopefully there's nothing wrong with that) 5 different players and I've used the following code: https://codepen.io/katzkode/pen/ZbxYYG

I'm trying to split the following loop in 5 different divs (5 different players, instead of #audio-players, there'd be a new div for each one):

```
function createAudioPlayers() {
    for (f in files) {
        var playerString = "<div id=\"audioplayer-" + f + "\" class=\"audioplayer\"><button id=\"playbutton-" + f + "\" class=\"play playbutton\"></button><div id=\"timeline-" + f + "\" class=\"timeline\"><div id=\"playhead-" + f + "\" class=\"playhead\"></div></div></div>";
        $("#audio-players").append(playerString);
    }
}
```

Here's the code to pull the files from:

```
var files = ["interlude.mp3", // 0
            "chooseyourweapon.mp3", // 1
            "interlude.mp3", // 2
            "scriptures.mp3",
       "scriptures.mp3"// 3
            ];
```

And I'm unsure how to proceed, I'm still learning. Thank you.

Comment: Your code already appears to be splitting up the five audio files correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you just need to loop the array. Use `forEach` for ease of understanding

```js
function createAudioPlayers() {
  files.forEach(function(f) {
    var playerString = "<div id=\"audioplayer-" + f + "\" class=\"audioplayer\"><button id=\"playbutton-" + f + "\" class=\"play playbutton\">" + f + "</button><div id=\"timeline-" + f + "\" class=\"timeline\"><div id=\"playhead-" + f + "\" class=\"playhead\"></div></div></div>";
    $("#audio-players").append(playerString);
  })
}


var files = ["interlude.mp3", // 0
  "chooseyourweapon.mp3", // 1
  "interlude.mp3", // 2
  "scriptures.mp3",
  "scriptures.mp3" // 3
];
createAudioPlayers()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="audio-players"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but it's not what I was looking for.

I'm trying to create separate div elements for that loop, to tickle them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
for (f of files) {
```

inplace of

```
for (f in files) {
```

For more details : https://bitsofco.de/for-in-vs-for-of/